# Error trying to use pthread on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, pthreads

I'm reading a tutorial about threads in C++ and tested the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

#define NUM_THREADS     5

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;
   cout << "Hello World! Thread ID, " << tid << endl;
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main ()
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   int i;
   for( i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ ){
      cout << "main() : creating thread, " << i << endl;
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, 
                      PrintHello, &threads[i]);
      if (rc){
         cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
         exit(-1);
      }
   }
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I've tried to compile this code using both gcc and g++, but I always get compilation errors.

Using gcc -pthread thread_test.c:

> /tmp/ccmpQLyp.o: In function `PrintHello(void*)':
>   thread_test.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to`std::cout'
>   thread_test.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
>   thread_test.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to`std::ostream::operator<<(long)'
>   thread_test.cpp:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
>   thread_test.cpp:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to`std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
>   /tmp/ccmpQLyp.o: In function `main':
>   thread_test.cpp:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to`std::cout'
>   thread_test.cpp:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
>   thread_test.cpp:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to`std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
>   thread_test.cpp:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
>   thread_test.cpp:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to`std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
>   thread_test.cpp:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `std::cout'
>   thread_test.cpp:(.text+0xd1): undefined reference to`std::basic_ostream >& std::operator<<  >(std::basic_ostream >&, char const*)'
>   thread_test.cpp:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
>   thread_test.cpp:(.text+0xe3): undefined reference to`std::basic_ostream >& std::endl >(std::basic_ostream >&)'
>   thread_test.cpp:(.text+0xeb): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
>   /tmp/ccmpQLyp.o: In function`__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
>   thread_test.cpp:(.text+0x141): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
>   thread_test.cpp:(.text+0x150): undefined reference to`std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
>   /tmp/ccmpQLyp.o:(.eh_frame+0x47): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Can you help? Do I have to do something so this code runs on Linux and Windows?

Comment: Try -lpthread instead

Comment: Using gcc with -lpthread I still get errors: /tmp/ccq3Kk7G.o: In function `main':
thread_test.cpp:(.text+0xb9): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
juliano@juliano-linux:~/Documents/cpp$ gcc -lpthread thread_test.cpp
/tmp/ccVu4YcA.o: In function `PrintHello(void*)':
thread_test.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `std::cout'
thread_test.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'

Comment: gcc -o thread_test.c -Wall -Werror -lpthread

Comment: @SChepurin : /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `g++` instead of `gcc`, or link `-lstdc++` manually.

Comment: Using g++ I'm getting the following error:  
/tmp/ccq3Kk7G.o: In function `main':
thread_test.cpp:(.text+0xb9): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 3):

For anyone reading this in 2020:

In GCC, when linking against pthread, don't use "-lpthread", but just the "-pthread" CLI options.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Got me past this error on Ubuntu 20.04, g++ 8

Answer (score 0):

It's important to know how the C++ compiler links the library files. Linking is the second step of *building a program*, the first one being Compilation which requires the header files.

As for linking, the linker program, **GNU ld**, does the job. When you run *gcc* or *g++* compiler command without *-c*, the *ld* program is run and the *libc*(the C standard library) is automatically searched and linked. As, implementation of pthread is NOT included in *libc*, we need to explicitly tell the linker(gcc/g++ pass the flags to the linker) to search *pthread* library. How to do that? Here it's from [gnu online docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)

> -llibrary
>
> -l library
>
> Search the library named library when linking. (The second alternative with the library as a separate argument is only for POSIX
> compliance and is not recommended.)
>
> The -l option is passed directly to the linker by GCC. Refer to your
> linker documentation for exact details. The general description below
> applies to the GNU linker.
>
> The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library.
> The directories searched include several standard system directories
> plus any that you specify with -L.
>
> Static libraries are archives of object files, and have file names
> like liblibrary.a. Some targets also support shared libraries, which
> typically have names like liblibrary.so. If both static and shared
> libraries are found, the linker gives preference to linking with the
> shared library unless the -static option is used.
>
> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the
> linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order
> they are specified. Thus, ‘foo.o -lz bar.o’ searches library ‘z’ after
> file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in ‘z’,
> those functions may not be loaded.

Like: `g++ thread.cc -lpthread -o thread`

Just prefix the library name with `-l`